# App not asking for permission to access location, popup stays in background

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, location, mapkit

I'm using the MapKit in my Swift iOS app.
The thing is that I'm requesting the permission to access the user location when the app is in use, but the first time I run the app in my iPhone, it stays frozen in the splash screen, because the permission request don't popup, but then, if I press the home button, the popup appears to ask for permission. And if I accept then, the next run the app works properly, but it shouldn't work like this.
So in the code, the debugger crashes here because he cannot get the permission:

```
let initialLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
```

Indicating the next issue: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1000b5d00)

So, I'm already asking the permissions in the viewWillAppear method:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    // locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    //locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
```

And I also have the entry in the Info.plist:  Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description.

Why is the popup not showing in the foreground but in the background?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers

EDIT:

I have an splash screen with the logo before the map view. Can this be the problem?

**EDIT 2 in answer to @Dan Clark**

Ok, I've added this check in the viewDidLoad as below:

**EDIT 3**

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    print("viewdidload")
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .AuthorizedWhenInUse    // Check authorization for location tracking
    {
        print("requestingautorization")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        print("afterrequestingauthorization")
       // LocationManager will callbackdidChange... once user responds
    } else {
        print("startupdatinglocation")
        addPins(locationManager)

    }  
}
```

But the popup requesting the authorization is not appearing :( I've got both prints before and after but the popup is not showing.

I also added the function you wrote me, in the same class.

```
    @nonobjc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("instatuscheck")
    switch status
    {
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        print("statusauthorized")
        addPins(manager)

    default:
        print("statusdefault")
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        // User denied access, handle as appropriate

    }
}
```

But I don't have it clear... this function will be called automatically when the authorization status changes?

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Hello, I've already added that key in the info.plist: Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description.

Comment: If both prints execute, I would have guessed it was the p-list entry, but you say that's covered. I notice that you say it gets stuck in the splash screen.  I haven't seen anything to this effect, but you may need to get to one of your views in order to allow the alert window to popup to ask for permission.  That would seem to fit with the home button allowing it to proceed to the dialog.  Maybe try the viewDidAppear method?  Also, yes the second method is a delegate callback function that gets called when there's a change in the authorization.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the update, with the modifications you told me, the app doesn't get stuck in the splash screen. The mapview is loaded but the authorization is never requested. So the in the map appears a large area without being focused in the user position, because the authorization is never given. Something is happening with the locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization(). I've tried with the viewDidAppear instead of the viewDidLoad but the behavior it's the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it can take a while for you to get authorized by LocationManager after you make the request.  Therefore, on your first try you don't have authorization before reaching the closure after your request.  I've addressed this by testing for authorization and, if I don't have it, putting in the request and then waiting for the callback to didChangeAuthorizationStatus before starting location updates.  If I already do have authorization, I immediately start location updates.

By the second time you run the app, you have the authorization so the delay doesn't occur and you're OK to go.

To try this approach, include this section in your ViewDidLoad (I'm assuming that you don't need to run this whenever your view appears, but only when it first starts):

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways     // Check authorization for location tracking
    {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()                    // LocationManager will callbackdidChange... once user responds
    } else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

And add this delegate function to your class to be called by LocationManager once you're authorized:

```
// If we've been authorized to use location, start the processes, otherwise abort the operation
// since we can't proceed without locations

@nonobjc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status
    {
    case .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    default:
        // User denied access, handle as appropriate

    }
}
```

Here's the code I use to instantiate / configure the locationManager:

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    [unowned self] in
    var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    _locationManager.delegate = self
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = [a user setting in my app]
    _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false  // So doesn't shut off if user stops to rest
    _locationManager.activityType = .fitness
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = Double([a user setting in my app])
    return _locationManager
    }()
```

This has been working for me so hopefully it will help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I've edited the question adding the things you wrote but still not working.

Comment: Also, is there any way to 'pause' the execution until the user allows the app to use its location?

Comment: Always gets tricky when threads come into play.  In effect, that's why I went to the callback after you get approval to proceed using the authorization to proceed.  If there's a lot to do, you could create a separate private function that performs the rest of the startup activities and call it either from the else case where you already have authorization or from the callback once you get it.

Comment: Hello again @DanClark . I've solved the problem of the disappearing popup. The problem was that the locationManager should be class-level instance variable, not a method-level one, inside of the viewDidLoad as I did before. So now, I can authorize the use of the location, but the delegate function is never called, when I allow the location permissions. I never see the prints of the `@nonobjc func locationManager` function. The function should be called automatically when the location is allowed right? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot the class-level issue.  Along those lines, when you set up the locationManager now do you make your class the delegate so you get the callback even if you aren't authorized?  For reference I'll add in my set up of the locationManager in an edit to the answer.

Comment: Hi @DanClark . In the first execution, I see the popup, and I allow the app to use my location, but the map stays in a wide range, without showing my position and without pins in the map, because the 'addPins()' function, is never called inside of the `case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:`. But if I execute again the app, as I previously give permissions to it, the 'addPins()' is executed in the viewDidLoad and the app works properly. Do you know why the function is not called in location permission status change? Thanks!

Comment: The possibility I mentioned was that [ locationManager.delegate = self ] wasn't getting set when you didn't have authorization so it didn't callback to the didChange function.  Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry @DanClark, I didn't understand you the first time ^^u. I've added the `locationManager.delegate = self` inside of the viewDidLoad, before the initial check of the status (as shown below the EDIT 3) and it seems the behavior is the same :( I cannot figure out why it's not working :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit stumped here.  I'll think about it some more...

Comment: Understood, thanks anyway for all your help and helpful replies :)

Comment: Hello @Dan , I've found the error. I've got to delete the '@nonobjc' from the function and now is working :) Thanks for your help! :D